# How do I move every file in a tree to the root of the tree?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I have a folder (let's call it A) with lots of subfolders B, C, D, E, which then again have subfolders B1, B2, B3, ... C1, C2, C3 ...

How can I using cmd move all files from all subfolders into the "root" folder A?

Comment: I am assuming you want every file in the one root, not in subfolders? So A\File1, A\File2, not A\Folder2\File1?

Comment: @Luke - Yes, you got it. Every file that exists in folders and subfolders moved to root.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> <sub>My original post neglected to include the file's extension in the move command.  `%~ni` only returns the basename, you need to use `%~nxi` to get both the filename and extension!  I hope you haven't mangled your filenames on my account!(</sub>

From a Command Prompt:

```
cd /d C:\Path\To\A
for /r %i in (*) do @move "%i" "%~nxi"
```

If you need to cleanup the empty folders afterward:

```
for /d %i in (*) do @rd /s /q "%i"
```

Now, if you have any filename clashes, you're on your own.  You can add the `/y` parameter to the `move` command (before the `"%i"`) to force overwrites.  If you want something different, you'll need another program that can auto-rename everything for you.

Also, if you want to use this in a batch file, change all the `%` to `%%`.

Comment: Didn't know about `FOR /r` -- nice!

Comment: Wow, very awesome.  I bow to your command-fu.

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder and copy all the other folders into it, then right click that folder and select *Search*.  In the search box enter `*.*`.

This will list all the files and folders.  Select all the files you want in your root directory and cut them.  Navigate to your root directory and paste all the files there.

Comment: search doesn't exist as a command in my cmd.

Comment: Richard wasn't talking about a a command. Have edited his answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Install Cygwin (or another Unix environment for Windows) and run the following:

```
cd A
find . -type f -exec mv {} . \;
```

Comment: Depending on your `mv` and `find` variants, you might need to use `find . -type f -exec mv -t . {} \;` instead.

Comment: For native Windows ports of many Unix tools I like http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Dennis UnxUtils are nice, unfortunately quite old by now. If you're using them at the moment, could you verify my post works with them? `mkdir -p a/a1 a/a2 a/a3 b/b1 b/b2 b/b3 c` and `touch a/a1/foo a/a1/bar a/a2/baz a/a3/qux b/b1/quux b/b2/quuux b/b3/quuuux c/ccc` for preparation.

Comment: -1 That may be true, but I was inquiring about how to do it in cmd.

Comment: @Daniel No doubt they are old, I have been dragging them around for years.  I just tried  `find . -type f -exec mv {} . ;` And it seemed to work ok.

Comment: @Idigas Cygwin's shell is based on `cmd.exe`. I wouldn't be surprised if `find.exe` worked without the Cygwin startup scripts. UnxUtils and MKS Toolkit at least are ports of Unix environments whose programs work in vanilla `cmd.exe`. Off the top of my head, I believe only Microsoft's own *SUA* don't actually use `cmd.exe`, and that's based on their documentation, not my own experience, so could be inexact.