# Is there a way to force WinRAR to unrar everything into one directory, regardless of

Tags: winrar

Is there a way to force WinRAR to unrar everything into one directory, regardless of its "internal structure"?

For example, you have an archive which consists of

```
- root directory: root files  
  + subdirectory1: sub1 files
  + subdirectory2: sub2 files
```

I want everything unrar'dt into one directory of my choosing, meaning I want in there *root files, sub1 and sub2 files*.

In short, *"destroy" the tree structure* inside the archive and just give me the files.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can uncheck the "relative/absolute pathname" option either under Tools/Options or during extraction. If it isn't available there, you can specify this when creating a new .RAR file:

[image]

It is located under the Files tab and called the File paths drop down box.

Alternatively, you might instead want to try to [move everything from the extracted folder to its root](https://superuser.com/questions/347979/how-do-i-move-every-file-in-a-tree-to-the-root-of-the-tree).

Comment: In my WinRAR 3.8b4 there is no Options under Tools, and there is only Settings under Options. In none am I finding the mentioned option.

Comment: @Idigas: Updated the answer with two options, if you can't do it while extracting. You can either create a new .RAR file (tedious) or create yourself a batch file to move everything from the extracted folder to its root.